# Python Win32: error when using SelectObject with HBITMAP

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, pywin32

I'm trying to select a DC with a HBITMAP, but I seem to get an error. I'm  using Pywin32 for Win32 functions as well as ctypes for the VirtualAlloc function.

```
data = VirtualAlloc(0, (x*y+x)*512,MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE)
hbm = CreateBitmap(x,y,1,32,data)
SelectObject(hdcdc, hbm)
```

Here's the error that occours when the code is executed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 32, in <module>
    SelectObject(hdcdc, hbm)
TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you get passed the python problems, this code doesn't really add up in terms of core Window API calls. Search for "pywin32 screen shot" if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please provide a *MCVE*. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke CreateDCFromHandle to create a DC object then use it's SelectObject method.

```
dc_hwnd = win32gui.GetWindowDC(desk_hwnd)
desk_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(dc_hwnd)
pen = win32ui.CreatePen(win32con.PS_SOLID, 10, win32api.RGB(255, 0, 0))
old_pen = desk_dc.SelectObject(pen)
```